# Show "..." at the end of a label if it is too wide

Tags: winforms, label

I know it is possible to set `MaximumSize` to prevent a label from resizing off of a form, but is it possible to also clip the text if necessary?

For example, if you pass the sentence `Hello, my name is Dave.` to a label, making the width greater than the maximum, I'd like it to show `Hello, my name is...`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [AutoEllipsis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and don't forget to set AutoSize to False

MSDN says:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the ellipsis character (...)
>   appears at the right edge of the Label, denoting that the Label text
>   extends beyond the specified length of the Label.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I just didn't know what it was actually called!